# Why would error say Column 'n' does not belong to table when it clearly does?

Tags: ms-access

I am running a Query from ASP.NET on a Microsoft Access database. The error states:  Column 'Area1' does not belong to table.

It looks like the error occurs here:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + columnName, progressRow[columnName]);
```

The sql command looks like this:

Extract.exe Warning: 0 : 03/09/2014 10:48:28 | CSUtilities | serengeti | Add Query : INSERT INTO Property (Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Area1,Area10,Area11,Area12,Area13,Area14,Area15,Area16,Area17,Area18,Area19,Area2,Area20,Area3,Area4,Area5,Area6,Area7,Area8,Area9,BlockFlag,CapitalValue,ConstructionYear,CurrentStock,Department,DepartmentFIS,DisposalDate,DisposalReason,DoubleBeds,DwellingType,DwellingTypeCode,EastingGridRef,ElevationGridRef,HeatingCode,HouseNumber,KeyBlockProperty,KeyCurrTcyId,KeyProperty,KeyPropertyTypeCode,KeyStreet,LocalPerm,NorthingGridRef,OwningDepartment,Postcode,PropertyClassCode,PropertyGroup,QLX,RepairResponsibility,RiskLevel,RTBCode,SingleBeds,StatPerm,Suffix,Telephone,TenureCode,UserCode,Void,WardCode,WaterCode, UpdateFlag) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Area1 is clearly defined in the Design View as a Short Text field.

I ran the following test manually and it works:

```
    INSERT INTO Property (Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Area1) VALUES ('Test1','Test','Test','Test','Test')
```

What is it playing at?

Comment: My mistake. The error was coming from somewhere completely different - progressRow[columnName]. Found it by adding the following: if (!progressRow.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName))
                        {
                            TraceFunctions.WarningMessage("Error  " + columnName + " does not exist in datarow.");
                        }

Answer (score 0):

It MIGHT be getting confused with the named parameters being the same as that of the column names (I've seen it before, but cant remember which engine).  Try changing your function of add parameters with value to   "@x" + column name... this way the OleDb driver won't be trying to look for a column Area1 to match with @Area1, but look for @xArea1 (and likewise for the rest).

One OTHER possibility is the data you are inserting too.  Might there be something with special characters like an "@" or "?" or similar in such fields that are confusing the post?